# WCF dual communication with java client

Tags: java, wcf, nettcpbinding, wsdualhttpbinding

I have to find a way to connect a WCF service to a Java client. I can not change the code of the WCF service and it only offers NetTcpBinding or wsDualHttpBinding

One work-around would be to create a C# communication channel to manage the communication between the service and the client. However I have no experience with C# and I'm sure this will take a long time.

What would be the best way to deal with this? Are there any available communication channels and offer this already?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is neither of the bindings offered support non-wcf clients.

I can't see any way you can communicate with this service without as you say put an intermediary service in between.

The **perfect** candidate for this is [WCF Routing protocol bridging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_whatsnewinwcf4_topic17.aspx) - which is exactly what it sounds like - translation of one protocol to another. In this case you are not going between protocols but WCF bindings.

Your solution would have to use `basicHttpBinding` which ships with WCF and exposes services over soap 1.1.

Comment: @zzirna any reason you un-accepted this answer? Thanks